# Recyclerview Delete item error with Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i have a recyclerview in my app which shows notes that was saved by the user in firebase database. On long pressing on a note, user gets an option whether to delete the note or not. Every note listed in the recyclerview gets deleted from the database and removed from the recyclerview except the last one. The last one gets removed from the database but is not cleared from the list. Once we go back to the mainactivity and then opens the savednotes activity again, the list is cleared.

Here's my code to the long button press:

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true)
                    .setTitle("Do you really want to delete this note?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String name = model.getNoteName();
                            String userId = auth.getUid();
                            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                    .getReference();
                            Query delete = reference.child("UserData").child(userId)
                                    .orderByChild("Note Name").equalTo(name);
                            delete.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot deleteSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        deleteSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                }
                            });



                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

I don't know what is missing or wrong here.. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

When clicking to remove an item, update the adapter:

```
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(which);
```

From the docs:

[`notifyItemRemoved`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemRemoved(int))

> `public final void notifyItemRemoved (int position)`

> Notify any registered observers that the item previ
> ously located at position has been removed from the data set. The items previously located at and after position may now be found at oldPosition - 1.

> This is a structural change event. Representations of other existing items in the data set are still considered up to date and will not be rebound, though their positions may be altered.

Comment: Well that was somewhat helpful. As I said the problem existed only with the last item in the list, I had to hardcode the position 0 into "list.remove(0)" and "notifyItemRemoved(0)". Then it worked perfectly.

Comment: isnt `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {`  which here giving u the position?

Comment: which is returning "-1" at every position